# Wire gauge on Drones different?

Tags: power, current, brushless-dc-motor, drone

How is it a 12 volt 40 amp wire in a car has to be approximately 16mm thick but a drone can use 3.5mm thick cable for 12 volt 120 amps.

What is the difference? They both have the same amount of power? How can a esc pull 120 amps from a battery but use ridiculously thin wire?

Comment: What esc is drawing 120A ? o_0

Comment: It was just a scenario, if you look on hobbyking.com at any esc's on there you can see many rated around that current rating and even higher.

Comment: Please one reference.

Comment: https://hobbyking.com/en_us/yep-150a-2-6s-sbec-brushless-speed-controller.html?___store=en_us

Comment: The wires on the picture are pretty thick.

Comment: Drones are also cooled better.  There's big fans over the hot wires.

Comment: Automotive cold crank current (when starting the engine) may be near 100A, and since it is also low supply voltage (12V), any significant voltage drop due to cable resistance could prevent the engine from starting. Automotive is also a harsh environment, with extreme temperatures and corrosive chemicals, so design margins have to be wider.

Comment: Does that car cable have to support the 1,000 amp starter current for 15 seconds at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in "rating", assuming higher responsibility and less liability in cases of automotive application (high temperatures etc.) as compared to drone application just for fun. Wires can withstand a lot of short term abuse before they evaporate. The drone application uses mostly open wires in high ambient air flow, while automotive wires are usually bundled and deeply enclosed. So the drone wires have better heat exchange with ambient, and therefore can carry higher ampacity.

If you check the [wire gauge table at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge), you will find out that a 3.3mm (AWG8) wire can hold 40 A with 60 deg.C temperature rise, and can hold about 470 A for 10 seconds before it overheats and destructs. So 120 A is possible for a short flight of a fun toy.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a wire to shift X amps from one place to another, there are two minimum criteria for size ...

a) The wire must not get too hot
b) The wire must not drop too much voltage, must get sufficient voltage to the load for the load to operate, and for efficiency

and two maximum criteria for size ...

c) The wire must not cost too much
d) The wire must not be too heavy

a) For currents in the low 10s of amps, an often-used rule of thumb is 10A/mm2. However, this applies to a few bundled wires, with no forced cooling, and normal PVC insulation which should not exceed 70C. If the wire is single, or is in a strong breeze, or is insulated with PTFE or other high temperature insulation, then that 10A/mm2 can be significantly exceeded.

b) This depends on the length as well as the area of the wire. In a drone, it may well be an order of magnitude shorter than the wire to a car tail light, so can tolerate being thinner.

c) This doesn't apply strongly to wires the length of drones or cars, and is included here for completeness. If you are wiring a town to a power station 100kms away, then it becomes rather important.

d) This will count strongly in drones, as every gram matters. It should certainly stop you putting in the next size larger wire 'just for luck'.

Comment: You can also add that in a drone, the wires are so short only losses on connectors matter.